# I don't understand how to use the async/await in Angular file upload

Tags: node.js, angular, async-await, promise

I am using Angular + Firebase for a simple web app. I have this function:

```
private async uploadFile(id: number, filePath: string, name: string, input: HTMLInputElement) : Promise<string> {
    const ext = filePath.split('.').pop();
    const path = '/' + id + '/' + name + '.' + ext
    const fileRef = ref(this.firebaseStorage, path);
    await uploadBytesResumable(fileRef, input.files[0]);
    let url: string = '';
    await getDownloadURL(fileRef).then((result: string) => {
      url = result;
    });
    console.log(url);
    return url;
  }
```

in which I want to upload a file in Firebase and return the string path (i.e. public url) of the image after it has been uploaded.

The problem is that the `getDownloadURL(fileRef)` returns a Promise and not a string, and I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to wait and unpack the promise to a string so that `uploadFile` can return a string value and not a promise!

I tried using the await keyword but the compiler still says it returns a Promise! What's the point then?

Edit:
This is how I use uploadFile:

```
    if (thumbnailStr != '') {
      thumbnailStr = this.uploadFile(id, this.blogForm.get('thumbnail').value, 'thumbnail', thumbnailImg);
    }
    if (backgroundStr != '') {
      backgroundStr = this.uploadFile(id, this.blogForm.get('background').value, 'background', backgroundImg);
    }
    console.log('url:', thumbnailStr);
    const blog = {
      'id': id,
      'blogDate': datetime,
      'heading': this.blogForm.get('heading').value,
      'subHeading': this.blogForm.get('subHeading').value,
      'blogDetail': this.blogForm.get('blogDetail').value,
      'thumbnail': thumbnailStr,
      'background': backgroundStr
    };
    this.blogs_service.addBlog(blog);
```

Edit #2: I figured it out. Making all functions asynchronous worked:

```
  private async uploadFile(id: number, filePath: string, name: string, input: HTMLInputElement) : Promise<string> {
    const ext = filePath.split('.').pop();
    const path = '/' + id + '/' + name + '.' + ext
    const fileRef = ref(this.firebaseStorage, path);
    await uploadBytesResumable(fileRef, input.files[0]);
    return await getDownloadURL(fileRef);
  }

  async addPost(thumbnailImg: HTMLInputElement, backgroundImg: HTMLInputElement) {
    ...
    if (thumbnailStr != '') {
      thumbnailStr = await this.uploadFile(id, this.blogForm.get('thumbnail').value, 'thumbnail', thumbnailImg);
    }
    if (backgroundStr != '') {
      backgroundStr = await this.uploadFile(id, this.blogForm.get('background').value, 'background', backgroundImg);
    }
    ...
```

P.S. I don't know why my question was marked as closed as I did not find the answer in the similar question but ok.

Comment: `const url = await getDownloadURL(fileRef);` should be all you need

Comment: I thought so too, but compiler says that url is a `Promise<string>` and not a `string`!

Comment: `so that uploadFile can return a string value and not a promise!` That's impossible. The value doesn't exist yet, so the best you can do is return a promise from `uploadFile`. Whatever code calls `uploadFile` will need to `await` that promise if it wants to know the value

Comment: Why is it impossible to block and wait for the value to become available, turning an async call to a sync call basically?

Comment: @Michael No. `url` - the result of an `await` operation - will never be a promise. However, `uploadFile` does of course return a promise, as it's an `async` function.

Comment: `Why is it impossible to block and wait for the value to become available` Javascript is, for the most part, single threaded. If you could block, you would not want to because it would lock up the entire browser. There is technically a function that does a synchronous http request, but `getDownloadURL` is (correctly) not written to use it. Since it doesn't use it, the code is asynchronous, and asynchronous code begets other asynchronous code. You can't take something that's asynchronous and make it synchronous in javascript.

Comment: You'll need to `await` the promise that it returns, i.e. `thumbnailStr = await this.uploadFile(…)`. It's still asynchronous, and so is the function that is adding the blog.

Comment: But to use `await` I have to make the outside/wrapper function asynchronous as well and this would never end. So if "asynchronous code begets other asynchronous code", that means I have no other option than to make the whole code asyncronous?

Comment: That's correct. Any code that needs to know when the data is available will need to be asynchronous as well. Promises are objects that represent future values. The only way to be notified when that value exists is to `await` the promise. (If a piece of code doesn't care when the data is available it need not `await` the promise)

Answer (score 2):

How are you calling your `uploadFile` function? It's important to remember that since it's an async function, it will always return a Promise.

Instead of using the `.then()` method within your `uploadFile` function, you might consider directly returning the result of the awaited Promise. This approach simplifies the function by utilizing the async/await syntax more effectively.

It can look like this:

```
private async uploadFile(...): Promise<string> {
  // ...
  // Wait to get the URL
  return await getDownloadURL(fileRef);
}
```

Remember, when you call this `uploadFile` function elsewhere in your code, you must handle the returned Promise. :)

Comment: Actually, i would like for `uploadFile` to be a syncronous function. I only added the async because I needed to to call await, which doesn't work in the way that I thought it did, i.e. turning an async call to a sync call. 

Is there another way to do this? I want uploadFile to be syncronous as shown by its usage in my edit.

Comment: It can't be synchronous since you're working with Promise, so you should handle it properly

Comment: Well, this kind of messes up my code... How do I do 2 async calls for example? In a nested way?

Comment: Do you want to do them sequentially or in parallel? For sequentially: `const result1 = await callOne(); const result2 = await callTwo();`. For parallel, `const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([callOne(), callTwo()]);`

Comment: Ohh nice, the parallel will be even better. Thank you!